# Splitting a matrix based on its contents in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix, vectorization

A matrix has m rows and n columns (n being a number not exceeding 10), and the nth column contains either 1 or 0 (binary). I want to use this binary as a decision to take out the associated row (if 1, or otherwise if 0). I understand that this can be done through iteration with the use of the IF conditional.

However, this may become impractical with matrices whose number of rows m gets into the hundreds (up to 1000). What other procedures are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`logical` datatypes for indexing](http://www.mathworks.in/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1). For example,

> M =
>
> ```
>  1     2     0
>  4     5     1
>  7     8     0
> ```

```
M = [1 2 0;4 5 1;7 8 0];
v = (M(:,n) == 1);
M(v,2) = 1;
```

> M =
>
> ```
>  1     2     0
>  4     1     1
>  7     8     0
> ```

Now you have set all the elements in column 2 to 1 if the corresponding element in column `n` is true.

Note that the `v = (M(:,n) == 1)` converts the `n`th column to a logical vector. You can accomplish the same with `v = logical(M(:,n));`

I would recommend this [blog entry](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) for a detailed look at logical indexing.

#### Update:

If you want to erase rows, then use:

```
M(v,:) = [];
```

Comment: I aim for something more along the lines of: if this row's last column element has the value of 1, I will erase that row from the matrix.